# Join attributes to nearest without repeating feature

Tags: qgis, attribute-joins, spatial-join

I have two layers, one of point and one of polygons, each with approximately 1000 features. I need to join the attributes of the points to the nearest polygons.

The problem is that point attributes cannot be repeated in more than one polygon, for example if point 1 has already been assigned to any polygon it cannot be assigned to another polygon.

Point -> Polygon

1     ->   A

2     ->   B

3     ->   C

4     ->   D

5     ->   E

I tried "nnjoin and join by nearest" but it doesn't allow iterating that way.
Does anyone know how it is possible to do this? I use QGIS.

Comment: What if you tried it the other way round?  Instead of assigning the nearest point to each polygon, and potentially getting the same point several times, try assigning the nearest polygon to each point.

Comment: Can you give more info about the use case? What happens if the k nearest points are already assigned to other polygons, you would assign a point that is further away? Should the point me contained in the polygon?